# File loader problems

Tags: c++

i have a text file which contains authors and books lists, i need to load it to my program, here is the code of the method which should load it:

```
void Loader::loadFile(const char* path)  
{

    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    char* bufferString;

    while (feof(file) != 1) {
        fgets(bufferString, 1000, file);
        printf("%s", bufferString);
    }
}
```

I use it in my main file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Loader* loader = new Loader();
    loader->loadFile("/home/terayon/prog/parser/data.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

And I get data.txt file is not completely printed.
What I should do to get data completed?

Comment: By the way, no need to do `new Loader()`, it's not needed in C++ (do you come from a Java background?). Instead just do `Loader loader;`

Answer (score 2):

[`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) reads into the memory pointed to by the pointer passed as first parameter, `bufferString` on your case.

But your `bufferString` is an uninitialised pointer (leading to undefined behaviour):

```
char * bufferString;
// not initialised,
// and definitely not pointing to valid memory
```

So you need to provide some memory to read into, e.g by making it an array:

```
char bufferString[1000];
// that's a bit large to store on the stack
```

As a side note: Your code is not idiomatic C++. You're using the IO functions provided by the *C* standard library, which is possible, but using the facilities of the C++ STL would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you have a pointer `bufferString` but you never actually make int *point* anywhere. Since it's not initialized its value will be *indeterminate* and will seem to be random, meaning you will write to unallocated memory in the `fgets` call.

It's easy to solve though, declare it as an array, and use the array size when calling `fgets`:

```
char bufferString[500];
...
fgets(bufferString, sizeof(bufferString), file);
```

---

Besides the problem detailed above, you should not do `while(!feof(file))`, it will not work as you expect it to. The reason is that the `EOF` flag is not set until you try to read from beyond the file, leading the loop to iterate once to many.

You should instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`

---

The code you have is not very C++-ish, instead it's using the old C functions for file handling. Instead I suggest you read more about the [C++ standard I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which is a auto-expanding string class that won't have the limits of C arrays, and won't suffer from potential buffer overflows in the same way.

The code could then look something like this

```
std::ifstream input_file(path);
std::string input_buffer;

while (std::getline(input_file, input_buffer))
    std::cout << input_buffer << '\n';
```